# C# network programming using lidgren with mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, lidgren

I'm currently writing a small online game using c# XNA and lidgren and I want to use mono + lidgren to write the server-program that is able to run on linux (cheaper hosting solutions). Is it possible to use lidgren and mono together? Should I use a different library or write my own socket solution with .NET functions?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Run lidgren through [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) and see if it is compatible with Mono.

Comment: How can I test Lidgren with MoMa when there is no assembly or exe to check? Should I check an exe that uses the lidgren library?

Comment: I'm down voting this because the question is easily answered yourself if you simply try using lidgren with mono. IMO: Try first, then ask questions.

Comment: Um, up-voting this old question because common and easily-answered questions are okay on SO! You can even find the answer yourself in five minutes, post it on SO (as long as no one already has), answer it, and save future searchers the effort. SO pages are often in the top 10 on Google for common search terms. Don't turn newbies off to SO by shunning perfectly valid questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Lidgren only requires System.Net.Sockets to run. MoMa only reports one minor issue;  NetworkInterface GetNetworkInterface() has [MonoTodo] set - it seems it currently only works on Linux and Windows (which might be good enough)

The distribution doesn't come with prebuilt binaries; but just load the solution and build it.